# zend framework save and execute POST request

Tags: zend-framework

Hello i have a website where if the login session times out i save the request like this

```
 Abc::saveThisUrl($this->getRequest());

 public static function saveThisUrl($url) {
        $lastPg = new Zend_Session_Namespace('history');
        $lastPg->url = $url;
    }
```

then after successful login i want to execute it

```
public static function getSavedUrl() {
        $lastPg = new Zend_Session_Namespace('history');
        if(!empty($lastPg->url)) {
            $path = $lastPg->url;
            $lastPg->unsetAll();
            return $path;
        }

        return ''; // Go back to index/index by default;
    }
```

so in my **AbcController.php**

```
public loginAction()
{
...//login succesfull
//i tried
$request = Abc::getSavedUrl(); /* @var $request Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract */
$this->setRequest($request);

$this->dispatch($request);
//or 
$this->run($request->getRequestUri());



//also tried
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
                    $front->setRequest($request);
                    return $front->dispatch($request);
}
```

both didn't work. I need to be able to execute **POST queries too**, many solutions on internet only care about URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out how

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->dispatch($request);

$this->getResponse()->clearBody();//otherwise it sends two time the same output
return;
//or die() instead of last 2 lines
```

and then this

```
/**
 * Get url from the session, to redirect after successfull login
 */
public static function getSavedUrl() {
    $lastPg = new Zend_Session_Namespace('history');
    if(!empty($lastPg->request)) {
        $path = $lastPg->request;

        /* $GLOBALS = $lastPg->GLOBALS;
        $_SERVER = $lastPg->_SERVER; */
        $_GET = $lastPg->_GET;
        $_POST = $lastPg->_POST;
        $_FILES = $lastPg->_FILES;
        $_REQUEST = $lastPg->_REQUEST;

        $lastPg->unsetAll();
        return $path;
    }

    return ''; // Go back to index/index by default;
}


/**
* Save url to the session, to redirect after successfull login
*/
public static function saveThisUrl($request) {
    $lastPg = new Zend_Session_Namespace('history');
    $lastPg->unsetAll();
    $lastPg->request = $request;

    /* $lastPg->GLOBALS = $GLOBALS;
    $lastPg->_SERVER = $_SERVER; */
    $lastPg->_GET = $_GET;
    $lastPg->_POST = $_POST;
    $lastPg->_FILES = $_FILES;
    $lastPg->_REQUEST = $_REQUEST;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get and save your module, controller, action and parameters instead of the url, and then call this in your `loginAction` :

```
$this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller, $module, array("param1" => $p1,
                                                                "param2" => $p2));
```

Comment: $request contains all those, however i then check for stuff like $this->_request->isPost(), and $_POST $_GET are not restored, i'm thinking i have to do it by hand

Comment: i'm not sure of what you want to check, but if you want to get request parameters you can access them this way `$this->_request->getParam("param1", false);`